# Deleting secondary calendar on google api python client gives unexpected error

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

as written on the google api python client documentation

[Deleting a secondary calendar(under python example)](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#deleting_calendar)

```
service.calendars().delete('secondaryCalendarId').execute()
```

this function call returns the following:
method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Does anyone have a clue what this error means? Clearly I just passed 1 argument and that is the calendarId that needs to be deleted. Or did anyone make this function work? Need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to supply the parameter name:

`service.calendars().delete(calendarId='secondaryCalendarId').execute()`

http://api-python-client-doc.appspot.com/calendar/v3/calendars